# Selecting rows where a given datetime is between two others doesn't work

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I am running into an issue that only occurs on our `MySQL 5.1` systems. It works fine on `MySql 5.6`.

I have a table that has two `DateTime` columns ("`start`" and "`end`"). I want to select all rows where a date is between these two columns or the same.
Basically this: `row.start <= MY_DATE_TIME <= row.end`

But when I execute this...

```
select * from alerts a
where a.start <= "2019-11-08 00:00:00"
and a.end >= "2019-11-08 00:00:00"
```

... I also get one row where the a.start is "2019-10-10 07:40:00" and a.end is "2019-11-20 23:55:00". My given date is clearly outside that range, so what am I doing wrong?

I also tried it like this with the same result:

```
select * from alerts a
where STR_TO_DATE("2019-11-08 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%D %T') between a.start and a.end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please debug the value first, like `select STR_TO_DATE("2019-11-08 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%D %T') as thedate` in order to check which value are you getting after the conversion :)

Comment: _"My given date is clearly outside that range"_ Isn't `11-08` between `10-10` and `11-20`?

Comment: omg. yes. holy hell. I didn't see that. Let me double-check our database... :D